# Android Studio doesn't recognize my imported Github project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Ok, so I decided to import my github [project](https://github.com/SanCampos/count)  into my other machine on AS. The problem however is that AS seems to completely forget it's an Android project and treats the project as a simple directory. I can't build, rebuild or even run my project. Additionally my file structure is gone.

I've tried importing based on external models but my Android Manifest can't seem to recognize my strings resource folder either. So importing is  out  of the question.

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: it's very general question, you might add more info..
and try to import project.!

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're missing a lot of the files that AndroidStudio creates with you start a new project.

A simple way to fix this will be to create a new project with the same name, package name, all that, and then just copy over your `app` folder.

When you reopen the project it will recognise it.

Comment: If you stick with the original directory or a copy, rather than selectively copying your individual custom files into a fresh project, it may also be necessary to delete auto-generated `.gradle` and `.idea` folders before re-opening the android project directory in Android Studio (these are hidden and usually gitignored, so probably won't show in git diffs of changes and are easy to miss)

Answer (score 1):

this happened to me due to that the file called `build.gradle` and other similar files wasn't in the root directory like when I opened my imported project I see these files :

[image]

but it should be like this :

[image]

so I navigated to the directory that contains the files in the above photos and imported that file as an android project and I succeeded, but there may other reasons for your problem , so you should clarify.

Comment: `.gradle` and `.idea` are auto-generated and might cache Android Studio's misinterpretations of what type of project this is, so after adding any missing Android files, if it still doesn't work, try deleting these then re-open the project

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a `build.gradle` in the root folder of the project, maybe that is the reason.

Comment: I had this. As soon as I added `gradle.settings` Android Studio automatically detected the project as an Android project.

Answer (score 0):

Without the build.gradle file android studio cannot perform a correct import of the project.